# Долгота и широта. Добавление линии в метрах

Tags: алгоритм, google-maps, карты, координаты

Хочу сделать модуль, который будет рисовать линию на карте определенной длина от назначенной точки и направления в который нужно рисовать.
Как правильно рассчитать крайнюю точку линии? Возможно ли это сделать?

Например, с точки 46.077234, 43.994934 нужно нарисовать линию 10 м.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делать придётся в два этапа.

На первом вы вычисляете длины проекций новой точки на параллель и на меридиан в метрах, а на втором должны перевести метры в градусы.

Классически нулю градусов соответствует направление вправо. На глобусе это будет направление на восток, и положительное направление угла против часовой стрелки. Если вам нужны другие нулевые значения, вначале надо преобразовать углы. Думаю, это несложно.

Так, пусть длина отрезка `l`, угол `α`. Длины проекций будут составлять:

```
m = sin(α) * l
p = cos(α) * l
```

Они будут в тех же единицах измерения, что и `l`, в вашем случае, в метрах. Их надо перевести в градусы. С проекцией на меридиан всё просто, все градусы на меридиане равны. С очень большой точностью длина Парижского меридиана составляет ровно 40 миллионов метров, так что длина одного градуса равна `40000000/360` метров.

А вот длина градуса параллелей убывает с ростом широты. На широте 90° (на полюсе) длина градуса равна 0, а на широте 0° (на экваторе) она максимальна. Форма Земли немного отличается от шара, и длина экватора равна 40075696 метров, соответственно, длина градуса на экваторе равна `40075696/360` метров, а длина градуса на широте `φ` равна `40075696/360 * cos(φ)` метров.

Сводим всё вместе.

Чтобы перевести метры в градусы, нам надо вычислить обратные величины.

```
m = (360 * sin(α) * l)/40000000
p = (360 * cos(α) * l)/(40075696 * cos(φ))
```

Помним, что это *длины проекций*, то есть их надо прибавить к первоначальным координатам, чтобы получить конечные координаты.

В вашем случае вы получите десятитысячные доли градусов, если речь идёт о расстоянии в 10-100 метров, и их надо будет прибавить к 46,077234 и 43,994934.

Comment: cos(φ) - это широта?

Comment: @Oswald *косинус широты*, если точно. Только широту сначала надо в радианы перевести.

Comment: Работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Да, возможно. Вероятно, подходящая функция может быть в библиотеках google maps. Если же нет, то подойдут формулы [с этой страницы](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), раздел **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point**

```
Formula:    
 φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
 λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
where   
  φ is latitude, 
  λ is longitude, 
  θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), 
  δ is the angular distance d/R; 
  d being the distance travelled, 
  R the earth’s radius

JavaScript:    (all angles     in radians)

var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));

The longitude can be normalised to −180…+180 using (lon+540)%360-180
```

Comment: Мне было больно это читать )

Comment: @Suvitruf Из-за форматирования? Чуть-чуть я подправлял при вставке.

Comment: Из-за формул. Боязнь всех этих `φ`, `δ` и т.п. в коде после скалы)